# How to disable link for team post types (RS Team Grid)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using a RS Team Grid to display our Team on a WordPress hosted site.

On the edit page there is a permalink that redirect to a page that I cannot find. When I go on the site, when someone clicks on the image of one of the members, it redirects them to a random page or there is a pop up saying content not found.

[image]

When I access my link, and I inspect the code, I see that there is an `<a href>`. How can I remove that hyperlink since I do not want to use it? Is there a way I can edit the php file or find a parameter to disable link for team post types?

Thank you.